# R processing on web site

Tags: r

I have a current project that consists of 3 parts:

1. An interface for clients to upload datasets from their equipment.
2. Process the uploaded datasets using R and some preset coefficients.
3. Display in a graph with a regression line, allowing the user to click points on the graph to remove them where needed and redraw the regression line automatically (after point removed).

Part 1: This is already done using PHP/Laravel. A simple upload and processing interface.

Part 3: I've been able to set this up in chart.js without any problems.

Part 2 is the sticking point at the moment. What I'd like is to be able to send the data to  an rscript and just get the datapoints back so that I can display them. Can anyone give suggestions as to the best way to do this? Is there an api available? Or do I need to install software on the server (not an issue if I do, but I'm hoping to avoid the need to if possible)?

TIA
Carton

Answer (score 0):

There is the package [shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) to do everything in R (user side GUI and server side R processing). Since you did it in PHP already, you can either write an R script that is being executed with a shell call from PHP, or build an R REST API with [plumber](https://www.rplumber.io/)

Comment: Hi Dan

Thanks for the reply. Executing a shell call from PHP sounds good. Would I need install anything on the server to achieve this?

Comment: You need to install R and the packages you want to use. Put everything into docker images whenever possible. However, dpepending on your codebase, the architecture of Laravel, R and chart.js does not look clear and consistent.